# How can we create dependency on several tests in testNg suite.xml

Tags: java, xml, testng

I am newbie to testNG and have created a suite.xml as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="test" verbose="0" allow-return-values="true">
  <test name="test1" preserve-order="true" >
   <classes>
      <class name="tests.checkLogin"/>
   </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="test2" preserve-order="true" >
   <classes>
      <class name="tests.fetchFromDB"/>
   </classes>
 </test>
 </suite>
```

All the tests are written in Java and here, checkLogin and fetchFromDB are classes in tests package.Now, my test1 gets failed due to some issue and I explicitly throw Runtime exception to fail it, this test gets successfully failed. However, test2 is called successfully after it.
My requirement is that if test1 fails then test2 should not be invoked.
Can anybody please help me how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Is test1 basically a setup step (guessing by it's name).  I somehow feel you have got your test design wrong.  For your problem, if you want to control this from your xml you can use the groups concept and create a dependency in the xml - [doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml)